# Why does this battery boost circuit work?

Tags: voltage, batteries, rectifier

[image]

Our equipment typically runs on 12 VDC as provided by the rectifier at the bottom of the diagram.

In a few locations, excessive cable length requires extra voltage. They installed two 1.5 VDC cells in series, with *one* wire going from the negative end terminal of the two-cell bank to the positive end terminal of the ten-cell bank. I verified the layout in the field, and the device in question will not operate when that wire is disconnected. How does this work?

Comment: Did you get a answer for this at reddit?

Comment: I did not! That's why I stopped by here.

Comment: Well you create a small supply 3 V above the 12 V rail. No wire, no 15 V rail.

Comment: They could have just put the two batteries in series with the other ones, but they didn't. If I take a meter reading on the bank of ten batteries, it shows the same voltage whether the extra wire is connected or not. But the equipment only works when the wire is connected.

Comment: What if you lift the ground (bottom left corner) on the upper charger?  I'm wondering if there is some other path that isn't shown; could also be a sneak path.

Comment: That is just a wiring diagram with mystery boxes that can contain anything internally. Show the internal schematics of the two boxes, preferably other sections too to see how they relate to each other, and the reason why it works can be found. Right now, those seemingly unrelated circuits are connected with one wire with no return path, unless it's the ground connection.

Comment: the diagram does not "look right" ... there is something missing or drawn incorrectly

Comment: The ground is just a case ground. The buses themselves are checked monthly per federal regulations to make sure they aren't grounded (critical safety devices... stray voltage could prevent them from activating). The black boxes are bridge rectifiers with smoothing capacitors.

Comment: What is the charger?  It must not be just a bridge.